# JPA newbie can't interact with database

Tags: java, database, orm, jpa, configuration

I started ussing JPA not long ago and I think it is great because of its annotations that make programming so simple. But I still have a lot few doubts that slow me down a bit (most of the times regarding to configuration issues):

1. I would like to understand the difference between the derby DB that comes in the OEPE(Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse), I was using this for my learning, and the popular MySQL DB(www.mysql.com). What confuses me is what is the difference with an embedded DB an a non embedded. What is better, what do you recommend?
2. The second doubt is regarding to some configuration issue I can't fix with my derby DB(not embedded mode) I already made a question, but I could not fix it. The problem is that when I try to access some of the tables of my DB(The tables exist in the database, they were created by the JPA feature generate Tables from entities), I get SQLSyntaxErrorException saying that the tables don't exist. I know that is impossible because that same query manually inserted in eclipses scrapbook works correctly. I know this have something to do some configuration issue, but I don't know what is it.
   I'll be really happy if someone with a bit more experience with JPA could give me a hand.

The tools I use for my programming are eclipse + OEPE, Java EE 6 and GlassfishV3.0

This is the link to my other question where I explain the issue in more detail:
[SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'BUYER' does not exist. What is missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512466/sqlsyntaxerrorexception-table-view-buyer-does-not-exist-what-is-missing)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding question 1:

Derby/JavaDB has two operation modes (quoted form [JavaDB documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/getstart/cgsintdo.html)):

**Embedded**

> Refers to Derby being started by a
>   simple single-user Java application.
>   With this option Derby runs in the
>   same Java virtual machine (JVM) as the
>   application. Derby can be almost
>   invisible to the end user because it
>   is started and stopped by the
>   application and often requires no
>   administration. The Derby
>   documentation often refers to this as
>   the embedded configuration or embedded
>   mode.

**Server (or Server-based)**

> Refers to Derby being started by an
>   application that provides multi-user
>   connectivity to Derby databases across
>   a network. With this option Derby runs
>   in the Java virtual machine (JVM) that
>   hosts the Server. Applications connect
>   to the Server from different JVMs to
>   access the database. The Derby Network
>   Server is part of the Derby software
>   distribution and provides this type of
>   framework for Derby. Derby also works
>   well with other, independently
>   developed Server applications. The
>   Derby documentation often refers to
>   this as the Network Server
>   configuration or client/server
>   configuration.

From my experience, the main differences of both modes are that in embedded mode, the database is part of your application and only one user can connect to the database.

In server mode, the database is not part of your application, runs in a different JVM or on another machine and operates in multi-user/multi-connection mode.

Regarding comparison of **JavaDB and MySQL**, I think it depends on your application and functional requirements. A quick google search revealed this [comparison of relational db systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems) (Derby can be found there under letter "A" for Apache Derby).

Comment: Great answer i didnt know that about embedded mode was actually that. I will give a look at that comparison table,maybe i switch to MySQL soon instead of Derby. Thanks

Comment: Switching to mySQL was a horrible experience, i went mad trying to configure it on windows. I went back to derby and y solved my doubt on question 2. I followed this tutorial and fixed the problem in a few mins: http://passogobbera.blogspot.com/2011/01/glassfish-v3-derby-db-configuration.html