# I created a table in my database and then deleted it. After creating another table I can't run the one frame where I used the old table

Tags: java, database, jdbc

```
run:
[EL Info]: 2016-11-02 19:12:53.768--ServerSession(1771878164)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b
[EL Info]: connection: 2016-11-02 19:12:54.574--ServerSession(1771878164)--file:/C:/Users/Denham  Lailvaux/Desktop/IT PAT 2016/build/classes/_ITPAT2016PU login successful
[EL Warning]: 2016-11-02 19:12:54.757--UnitOfWork(1584364142)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'NBUSER.MEMBERDETAILSTB' does not exist.
Error Code: -1
Call: SELECT IDNumber, BirthDate, FeeStructure, MemberUsername, MembershipType, PremiumMember, Sex, TotalMembershipFee, Trainer FROM NBUSER.MemberDetailsTB
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=MemberDetailsTB sql="SELECT IDNumber, BirthDate, FeeStructure, MemberUsername, MembershipType, PremiumMember, Sex, TotalMembershipFee, Trainer FROM NBUSER.MemberDetailsTB")
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'NBUSER.MEMBERDETAILSTB' does not exist.
Error Code: -1
Call: SELECT IDNumber, BirthDate, FeeStructure, MemberUsername, MembershipType, PremiumMember, Sex, TotalMembershipFee, Trainer FROM NBUSER.MemberDetailsTB
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=MemberDetailsTB sql="SELECT IDNumber, BirthDate, FeeStructure, MemberUsername, MembershipType, PremiumMember, Sex, TotalMembershipFee, Trainer FROM NBUSER.MemberDetailsTB")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:468)
    at ITPAT2016pkg.RegisterUI.initComponents(RegisterUI.java:37)
    at ITPAT2016pkg.RegisterUI.<init>(RegisterUI.java:20)
    at ITPAT2016pkg.RegisterUI$5.run(RegisterUI.java:666)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'NBUSER.MEMBERDETAILSTB' does not exist.
Error Code: -1
Call: SELECT IDNumber, BirthDate, FeeStructure, MemberUsername, MembershipType, PremiumMember, Sex, TotalMembershipFee, Trainer FROM NBUSER.MemberDetailsTB
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=MemberDetailsTB sql="SELECT IDNumber, BirthDate, FeeStructure, MemberUsername, MembershipType, PremiumMember, Sex, TotalMembershipFee, Trainer FROM NBUSER.MemberDetailsTB")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1995)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2714)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2667)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1202)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2894)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1797)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1779)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1744)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'NBUSER.MEMBERDETAILSTB' does not exist.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1551)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1500)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:619)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Table/View 'NBUSER.MEMBERDETAILSTB' does not exist.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatementX(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: `Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'NBUSER.MEMBERDETAILSTB' does not exist.` Debug your code using the debugger and please format this stack trace

Comment: @Denham man I was scared looking at your question :D

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512466/sqlsyntaxerrorexception-table-view-buyer-does-not-exist-what-is-missing

Comment: If you dropped the table, the obviously you can't select from it anymore. You need to remove the code that uses the non-existing table (or re-create the table)